# Can Visual Studio or an addon highlight CSS classes that are not defined?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, google-chrome-devtools

I need to check several pages for HTML that is linking to a CSS class that is not defined.  In the C# code it does this obviously as it will generate a compiler error but I cannot find a way to easily check HTML in a MVC app to see if it is linking to a CSS class that is not defined.

In Chrome developer tool I can see all the CSS from my CSS file that I have declared and not used, but not the CSS class selectors in the HTML that are not defined.  All CSS validators I have tried just ignore the fact a class has been called like:

```
<div class="doesntExist"></div>
```

I understand this is a design choice because classes can be declared dynamically but is there anyway to get VS2013 to generate a warning or a third party tool that will do this?  It will make what I have to do a lot easier.